# Markdown global definition of abbreviations

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am generating web pages using Jekyll and Markdown. I want to include definitions of standard acronyms on every page. The definition for a sample acronym will look like this:

```
* [PR]: Programming Renaissance
```

I would like to include these acronym definitions on every page in Jekyll but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you store definitions in `_includes/definitions.md` file, you can use `{% include definitions.md %}` to append it to other markdown files. Files will be joined before converted to html so the effect of abbreviation should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If the acronym definitions are the same on every page then you can just create a html file inside `/_includes` and then in every page markdown reference it as `{% include definitions.html %}`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To generalize my question. What I am attempting to do is to include some Markdown source in every file before it is processed by Markdown, i.e. via an "include" directive for Markdown; Including HTML is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by way of the [include_relative](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file). Something like this should work:

```
---
layout: default
---

Your text here

{% include_relative acronyms.md %}
```

You must place the file `acronyms.md` within the `_posts` directory or one of its subdirectories. It also works with html files.